# How to restrict flutter webview from navigating to hyperlink conditionally?

Tags: ios, flutter, webview

I'm using webview_flutter (version: 4.4.1) to show the below HTML content using webView. The hyperlink navigation works and opens up the link in the relevant browser but the webview screen also navigates to hyperlink, causing the user see the same screen twice on the back press from browser.

How to restrict the webview from navigating to hyperlink?

```
data:text/html;charset=utf-8;base64,PGhlYWQ+PG1ldGEgbmFtZT0 .....
```

say the implementation goes as below:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final WebViewController controller = WebViewController()
      ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
      ..setNavigationDelegate(_navigationDelegate())
      ..loadRequest(_getFormattedHtml(context, html));
    return WebViewWidget(controller: controller);
  }

  Uri _getFormattedHtml(BuildContext context, String html) {
    final css = _css(context); // some styling

    final content = '<head>'
        '<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0">'
        '<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=myFont" rel="stylesheet">'
        '<style>$css</style>'
        '</head>'
        '<body><div class="container">$html</div></body>';

    return Uri.dataFromString(
      content,
      mimeType: 'text/html',
      encoding: Encoding.getByName('utf-8'),
    );
  }
```

and the NavigationDelegate is:

```
    NavigationDelegate _navigationDelegate() => NavigationDelegate(
      onNavigationRequest: (NavigationRequest request) async {
          final urlString = request.url;
          if (!urlString.startsWith('data')) {
            await launchUrlString(
              urlString,
              mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication,
            );
          }
          return NavigationDecision.navigate;
        },
      );
```

Found `setNavigationDelegate` method called even in initial call, hence forced to check and allow content starting with 'data'. Else, iOS browser won't show any content.

What I'm looking for is to

- display supplied HTML in webview
- Navigate any hyperlink to browser on user click
- show to extract page in webview when user returns from browser